# Default path in .NET (e.g. in Picturebox.Load())

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

When I run `SomePicturebox.Load("Foo.bmp")` and there is a Foo.bmp in the application's startup folder, it will load this image. However I have a case where the image is not loaded (when the application is started by an installer, namely).

Now I am wondering: Is there a default path that is searched by the framework when the path is not fully qualified? How can I show this path at runtime (to reveal why the image is not loaded in some cases)?

I tried looking at the `Picturebox.ImageLocation` property but this said just "Foo.bmp" without a path.

This is related to WinForms, .NET Framework 4.

Answers in both C# and VB.NET are very welcome.

Comment: It almost always will use the application's [*current working directory*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx).

Comment: This is the correct method @JonathonReinhart in my case as I pointed out in a comment below. If you could add it as an answer I can close this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET

```
Dim directory as String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

In C#

```
string directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

I tested and AlexC was correct and I have updated this answer.

Comment: Do you mean AppDomain.CurrentDomain?

Comment: The first two aren't correct, afaik. Application.UserAppDataPath is for obtaining a path that is part of the users roaming profile, and the Application class doesn't have a property called BaseDirectory.

Comment: Well I did some testing with a nonworking version with no error handling and turns out it searches in "C:\Windows\system32". So unfortunately non of the above answers reflect this path. However  Jonathon Reinhart's comment above suggested `IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` which is the way to go for this. Thank you nontheless!

Comment: Another SO win. Glad it worked out. Jonathon should make an actual answer post so you can mark it. For search reasons

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the current value for the path is with `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.

Rather than dealing with this ambiguity, though, it is better to make sure you fully qualify the path. To get paths on a system that can change, you should use the `System.Environment.GetFolderPath` call. For example, if you want the user's documents folder:

```
var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

If you happen to be using an open file dialog the following is another call I often find helpful:

```
var fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(selectedFile);
```

There are quite a few other routines in the System.IO.Path namespace that can help you with making sure that your file and path names are always fully qualified. Hope these help!

**Note** - My answer is in C#

Comment: You are absolutely correct that this should always be done. The reason for my problem however is a bit more complex  (the function is actually called by a third party DLL that I can't edit which reads the path from an .ini file as plain text with no wildcards. This failed when the application was started through an installer). I just broke it down to the essentials.